# Disable screen lock pattern

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, lock-screens, htc-one-x, pattern-lock

I just downloaded JellyBean on my HTC One X.

I wanted to check APNs, but accidently went to VPN. Then, I had to set the screen lock pattern to access it. Now, I have an extra step when I want to use the phone. Is there any way to disable the screen lock pattern?

Comment: Have you checked in *Settings -> Security -> Screenlock*?

Comment: Yes screen lock only shows the pattern to draw on, the only option is to a time frame to keep phone unlocked up to 15 mins. I may have to do a factory reset.

Answer (score 2):

First, remove the VPN entry. Settings will not let you remove the pattern unlocker until you do so.

Then choose a "Slide" option from Settings -> Security -> Screen Lock

I had the same problem and this works

Answer (score 0):

You can disable screen locks by going to `Settings -> Security -> Screen Lock`

<sup>On a side note, it's a good practice to use a screen lock, preferably a pattern, a PIN or a password.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

My mistake for the previous answer .

As you have a VPN defined you are probably facing difficulty accessing the network as you need to unlock the screen every time you access so I suggest you download this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.did.vpnroot&hl=en).

In this app it will remove the requirement for any pattern lock to access the network thereby relieving you of the problem which you face .

Else if you still want to disable the lock then go [through with this](http://blog.johnrbussiculo.com/2013/05/i-love-my-new-htc-one-but/)

Comment: You can't remove the pattern lock if you have a VPN defined.